# Calling an expensive Reactive Extensions `IObservable` function only when values not in local cache

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm using the Reactive Extensions (Rx) and a repository pattern to facilitate getting data from a relatively slow data source. I have the following (simplified) interface:

```
public interface IStorage
{
    IObservable<INode> Fetch(IObservable<Guid> ids);
}
```

Creating an instance of the implementation of `IStorage` is slow - think creating a web service or db connection. Each `Guid` in the `ids` observable results in a one-to-one `INode` (or `null`) in the return observable and each result is expensive. Therefore , it makes sense to me only to instantiate `IStorage` only if I have at least one value to fetch and then to use `IStorage` to fetch only the values once for each `Guid`.

To limit the calls to `IStorage` I cache the results in my `Repository` class that looks like this:

```
public class Repository
{
    private Dictionary<Guid, INode> NodeCache { get; set; }

    private Func<IStorage> StorageFactory { get; set; }

    public IObservable<INode> Fetch(IObservable<Guid> ids)
    {
        var lazyStorage = new Lazy<IStorage>(this.StorageFactory);

        // from id in ids
        // if NodeCache contains id select NodeCache[id]
        // else select node from lazyStorage.Value.Fetch(...)
    }
}
```

In the `Repository.Fetch(...)` method I've included comments indicating what I'm trying to do.

Essentially though, if the `NodeCache` contains all of the ids being fetched then `IStorage` is never instantiated and the results are returned with almost no delay. However, if any one id is not in the cache then `IStorage` is instantiated and all of the unknown ids are passed through the `IStorage.Fetch(...)` method.

The one-to-one mapping, including order preservation, needs to be maintained.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to work it out, but I finally got my own solution.

I have defined two extension methods called `FromCacheOrFetch` with these signatures:

```
IObservable<R> FromCacheOrFetch<T, R>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, R> cache,
    Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<R>> fetch,
    IScheduler scheduler)
        where R : class

IObservable<R> FromCacheOrFetch<T, R>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, Maybe<R>> cache,
    Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<R>> fetch,
    IScheduler scheduler)
```

The first uses standard CLR/Rx types and the second uses a `Maybe` monad (nullable types not restricted to value types).

The first just turns the `Func<T, R>` into `Func<T, Maybe<R>>` and calls the second method.

The basic idea behind is that when the source is to be queried the cache is examined for each value to see if a result already exists and if it does the result is immediately returned. If, however, any result is missing then and only then is the fetch function called by passing in a `Subject<T>` and now all cache misses are passed through the fetch function. The calling code is responsible for adding the results to the cache. The code asynchronously processes all the values through the fetch function and reassembles the results, along with cached results, into the correct order.

Works like a treat. :-)

Here's the code:

```
public static IObservable<R> FromCacheOrFetch<T, R>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, R> cache, Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<R>> fetch,
    IScheduler scheduler)
        where R : class
{
    return source
        .FromCacheOrFetch<T, R>(t => cache(t).ToMaybe(null), fetch, scheduler);
}

public static IObservable<R> FromCacheOrFetch<T, R>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, Maybe<R>> cache, Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<R>> fetch,
    IScheduler scheduler)
{
    var results = new Subject<R>();

    var disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    var loop = new EventLoopScheduler();
    disposables.Add(loop);

    var sourceDone = false;
    var pairsDone = true;
    var exception = (Exception)null;

    var fetchIn = new Subject<T>();
    var fetchOut = (IObservable<R>)null;
    var pairs = (IObservable<KeyValuePair<int, R>>)null;

    var lookup = new Dictionary<T, int>();
    var list = new List<Maybe<R>>();
    var cursor = 0;

    Action checkCleanup = () =>
    {
        if (sourceDone && pairsDone)
        {
            if (exception == null)
            {
                results.OnCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
                results.OnError(exception);
            }
            loop.Schedule(() => disposables.Dispose());
        }
    };

    Action dequeue = () =>
    {
        while (cursor != list.Count)
        {
            var mr = list[cursor];
            if (mr.HasValue)
            {
                results.OnNext(mr.Value);
                cursor++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    Action<KeyValuePair<int, R>> nextPairs = kvp =>
    {
        list[kvp.Key] = Maybe<R>.Something(kvp.Value);
        dequeue();
    };

    Action<Exception> errorPairs = ex =>
    {
        fetchIn.OnCompleted();
        pairsDone = true;
        exception = ex;
        checkCleanup();
    };

    Action completedPairs = () =>
    {
        pairsDone = true;
        checkCleanup();
    };

    Action<T> sourceNext = t =>
    {
        var mr = cache(t);
        list.Add(mr);
        if (mr.IsNothing)
        {
            lookup[t] = list.Count - 1;
            if (fetchOut == null)
            {
                pairsDone = false;
                fetchOut = fetch(fetchIn.ObserveOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool));
                pairs = fetchIn
                    .Select(x => lookup[x])
                    .Zip(fetchOut, (i, r2) => new KeyValuePair<int, R>(i, r2));
                disposables.Add(pairs
                    .ObserveOn(loop)
                    .Subscribe(nextPairs, errorPairs, completedPairs));
            }
            fetchIn.OnNext(t);
        }
        else
        {
            dequeue();
        }
    };

    Action<Exception> errorSource = ex =>
    {
        sourceDone = true;
        exception = ex;
        fetchIn.OnCompleted();
        checkCleanup();
    };

    Action completedSource = () =>
    {
        sourceDone = true;
        fetchIn.OnCompleted();
        checkCleanup();
    };

    disposables.Add(source
        .ObserveOn(loop)
        .Subscribe(sourceNext, errorSource, completedSource));

    return results.ObserveOn(scheduler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I assumed you want to instantiate the storage only once for all subscribers):

```
public class Repository
{
    public Repository()
    {
        _lazyStorage = new Lazy<IStorage>(StorageFactory);
    }
    private readonly Lazy<IStorage> _lazyStorage;
    private Dictionary<Guid, INode> NodeCache { get; set; }
    private Func<IStorage> StorageFactory { get; set; }
    public IObservable<INode> Fetch(IObservable<Guid> ids)
    {
        return Observable
            .CreateWithDisposable<INode>(observer =>
                ids.Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    INode node;
                    if (NodeCache.TryGetValue(x, out node))
                        observer.OnNext(node);
                    else
                    {
                        node = _lazyStorage.Value.Fetch(x);
                        NodeCache[x] = node;
                        observer.OnNext(node);
                    }
                }, observer.OnError, observer.OnCompleted));
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Hmm, this order preservation while IStorage.Fetch asynchronous is interesting - waiting for IStorage.Fetch should block all future values... Thinking...

I think I got it... Maybe... If you need order preservation, you need a queue. In RX world, queue is .Concat. Would the below work for you?

```
public class Repository
{
    public Repository()
    {
        _lazyStorage = new Lazy<IStorage>(StorageFactory);
    }
    private readonly Lazy<IStorage> _lazyStorage;
    private Dictionary<Guid, INode> NodeCache { get; set; }
    private Func<IStorage> StorageFactory { get; set; }
    private IObservable<INode> Fetcher(Guid id)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
        {
            INode node;
            return NodeCache.TryGetValue(id, out node)
                ? Observable.Return(node)
                : _lazyStorage.Value.Fetch(id).Do(x => NodeCache[id] = x);
        });
    }
    public IObservable<INode> Fetch(IObservable<Guid> ids)
    {
        return ids.Select(Fetcher).Concat();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this doesn't work. The `IStorage.Fetch` method takes `IObservable<Guid>`, not `Guid`, and returns an observable too, thus should only be called once and the observables do the work.

Comment: You're still calling `IStorage.Fetch` as if it were `INode Fetch(Guid id)`. It's `IObservable<INode> Fetch(IObservable<Guid> ids)`. Also, a new `Lazy<IStorage>` should be created for each `Repository.Fetch` call. :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity - In the second example, IStorage.Fetch is called as an IObservable<INode>(Guid id). Please explain what is the reason for **passing in** an observable, and not a single value. As for storage creation, it is your call - you can move it within Repository.Fetch (bad practice though)

Comment: @Enigmativity - If the reason for IStorage.Fetch to take in an observable is a "it is an existing component" then _lazyStorage.Value.Fetch(id) can be replaced with _lazyStorage.Value.Fetch(Observable.Return(id))